# Reinstall Windows 10 1909 Enablement Package?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1909

I updated my Windows 10 installation to version 1909 using the Enablement Package. Shortly afterward, my system started behaving very strangely, so naturally the first thing I did was uninstall the update. Turns out it wasn't the cause, my power supply had coincidentally decided to fail. Now I'd like to reinstall the Enablement Package. How can I do this? In "Check for Updates", Windows 10 is now offering to download and install "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1909", but I strongly suspect this is going to be the traditional feature update experience, not the ultra-fast Enablement Package.

Comment: [Enablement Package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517245/feature-update-via-windows-10-version-1909-enablement-package) if anyone is wondering.  The only method to install this update is through Windows Update and/or WSUS which isn't applicable in your case.  What is the last cumulative update you have installed?

Comment: If you have Windows 10 Professional you can try defer feature updates to something like 7 days.  This might result in the update being offered again, otherwise, if you want any features that were included in 1909, you must install 1909 at this point

Comment: I tried doing the defer updates thing, but when I re-enabled updates, it didn't find anything new. So, my only option now is to do the 1909 update the old way, and wait an hour or more while it churns instead of updating to 1909 in a single reboot with no special update installation step? :-(

Comment: Under "View update history", it currently lists two feature updates, it says "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903" was installed back in July and "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1909 (2)" was installed last Wednesday. `winver` says "Version 1903".

Comment: When I installed 1909 on my system it took less than 10 minutes to install

Comment: I don't see any evidence of a way to re-arm the Enablement Package, so I guess I'll just have to bite the bullet and see how long it takes. For reference, my laptop at work took 2.5 hours to update from 1903 to 1909 without the Enablement Package. Here's hoping my experience is closer to yours :-)

Comment: Okay, the reinstallation of 1909 did not take 2.5 hours like my other experience. It was relatively quick after all. I'm not sure if that generalizes, but if anyone else is in the same boat, I guess my advice is to make sure it won't be the end of the world if it takes a long time and then just do it. :-)